# Ansible - pass fact between plays when one host is a variable

Tags: ansible, hostvars

I have a playbook that contains two plays.

- The first play does some data gathering, creates some facts and finally a dynamic inventory.
- The second play uses the dynamic inventory from the first and, tries (but fails) to use some facts from the first.

I understand (ish) that the facts created are associated with the hosts of the individual plays and, *hostvars* could normally be used for this purpose. The trouble i'm having, in my first play, the *hosts* are defined as a variable that gets passed in as an extra var when calling the playbook. I don't know how to use hostvars in this scenario.

**For reproduction of the issue**
*inventory* is as follows

```
[p1]
mgmt_server_01.us.acme.com

[p1:vars]
password = "something"

[p2]
mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com

[p2:vars]
password = "something_else"

[p3]
mgmt_server_03.emea.acme.com

[p3:vars]
password = "yet_another_something"

[mgmt_servers:children]
p1
p2
p3

[mgmt_servers:vars]
username = "admin"
```

The "dynamic inventory" is *sample.json*

```
{
    "servers": [
        "server01.us.acme.com",
        "server03.us.acme.com",
        "server04.us.acme.com",
        "server02.us.acme.com"
    ]
}
```

The playbook is *dynamic_inv.yml*

```
---
- hosts: "{{ upgrade }}"
  name: Read sample of servers from json and create dynamic inventory. Tasks happen for ALL inventory Servers
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    json_var: "{{ lookup('file', './sample.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: set json_var to fact
      set_fact:
        my_fact: "{{json_var}}" 

    - name: Read json to get sample servers 
      debug:
        msg: "Server names are {{item}}"
      with_items: "{{json_var.servers}}"

    - name: Create dynamic inventory from json_vars
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: sample_group
      with_items: "{{ json_var.servers }}"
      no_log: false

    - name: Print the dynamic inventory
      debug:
        var: groups.sample_group

- hosts: sample_group
  name: tasks iterate sequentially, one server at a time
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  order: sorted
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Print something to show the flow of the playbook
      debug: msg="This line is printed in the beginning for activity on each sample server in the inventory"
    
    - name: Print the Server name
      debug:
        msg: "The Server name is {{inventory_hostname}}"
    
    - name: Print something from my_fact
      debug: 
        msg: "something from my_fact is {{item}}"
      with_items: "{{my_fact}}"
```

To run the playbook
**ansible-playbook testing/dynamic_inv.yml -i testing/inventory -e upgrade=mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com**

The error returned is

```
TASK [Print the dynamic inventory] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com] => {
    "groups.sample_group": [
        "server01.us.acme.com",
        "server03.us.acme.com",
        "server04.us.acme.com",
        "server02.us.acme.com"
    ]
}

PLAY [tasks iterate sequentially, one server at a time] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Print something to show the flow of the playbook] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server01.us.acme.com] => {
    "msg": "This line is printed in the beginning for activity on each sample server in the inventory"
}

TASK [Print the Server name] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server01.us.acme.com] => {
    "msg": "The Server name is server01.us.acme.com"
}

TASK [Print something from my_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [server01.us.acme.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'my_fact' is undefined"}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server01.us.acme.com       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How can i modify the following to use hostvars when the first host is passed as an extra variable ?

```
    - name: Print something from my_fact
      debug: 
        msg: "something from my_fact is {{item}}"
      with_items: "{{my_fact}}"
```

Are hostvars the best option or, is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a separate `set_fact` task, set the variable directly on the newly created hosts:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ upgrade }}"
  name: Read sample of servers from json and create dynamic inventory. Tasks happen for ALL inventory Servers
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    json_var: "{{ lookup('file', 'sample.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Create dynamic inventory from json_var
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: sample_group
        my_fact: "{{ json_var }}"
      loop: "{{ json_var.servers }}"

- hosts: sample_group
  name: tasks iterate sequentially, one server at a time
  gather_facts: false
  order: sorted
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Print something from my_fact
      debug: 
        msg: "something from my_fact is {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_fact | list }}"
```

This results in:

```
PLAY [Read sample of servers from json and create dynamic inventory. Tasks happen for ALL inventory Servers] ***

TASK [Create dynamic inventory from json_var] **********************************
changed: [mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com] => (item=server01.us.acme.com)
changed: [mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com] => (item=server03.us.acme.com)
changed: [mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com] => (item=server04.us.acme.com)
changed: [mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com] => (item=server02.us.acme.com)

PLAY [tasks iterate sequentially, one server at a time] ************************

TASK [Print something from my_fact] ********************************************
ok: [server01.us.acme.com] => (item=servers) =>
    msg: something from my_fact is servers

PLAY [tasks iterate sequentially, one server at a time] ************************

TASK [Print something from my_fact] ********************************************
ok: [server02.us.acme.com] => (item=servers) =>
    msg: something from my_fact is servers

PLAY [tasks iterate sequentially, one server at a time] ************************

TASK [Print something from my_fact] ********************************************
ok: [server03.us.acme.com] => (item=servers) =>
    msg: something from my_fact is servers

PLAY [tasks iterate sequentially, one server at a time] ************************

TASK [Print something from my_fact] ********************************************
ok: [server04.us.acme.com] => (item=servers) =>
    msg: something from my_fact is servers

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
mgmt_server_02.apac.acme.com : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server01.us.acme.com       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server02.us.acme.com       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server03.us.acme.com       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server04.us.acme.com       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I also did some other cleanup. For example, `connection: local` does nothing when everything you're running is controller-side tasks like `debug` and `add_host`. If your full playbook also runs some normal modules that you want to execute on the controller you should use [`delegate_to: localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks) instead of messing with the connection settings, because that has some weird, unintuitive side effects.